# How to stop the Matlab from rearranging symbolic variables?

Tags: matlab, expression, symbolic-math, simplification

This symbolic expression in Matlab

```
syms x y;
f = x * y * y
```

returns

```
f =

x*y^2
```

How can I stop Matlab from simplifying the expression and let it remain as `x * y * y`?
I'm trying to print the steps of a calculation this way, so reordering the terms causes confusion.

Comment: Can you provide a full (simple) example of the big picture? I mean, are you trying to print the steps in the process of simplifying `f`? If not, why aren't you happy with the expression MATLAB yields?

Comment: @EitanT No, I'm trying to implement a more complicated numerical method (or any algorithm) and I'd like to output some of the expressions generated in those steps, so that a trainee will be able to follow how things are going on.

Comment: @EitanT I need the order preserved for derivation

Answer (score 1):

A workaround that I can think of, is something like this:

```
str = 'f = x * y * y' ;
```

Then

```
eval(str);
```

will perform the operation you want and you can still use str for presenting it.

Comment: Is there any way to preserve it after the evaluation? I need to keep variable order for the sake of derivatives.